# Maximum length of Custom Dimension value?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

As the title says :
What is the maximum length of a string that can be stored inside a custom dimension in google analytics?

Comment: It's 150 bytes and it's in the [G Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#dimension)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the maximum length of Custom Dimension value must not exceed 150 bytes.

- If you are using plain test, it can be upto: 150 characters (best case)
- Worst case: -  37 characters

There are various tools to calculate the bytes out of Characters. One of it I found: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

[image]

**Reference**: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#dimension

---

### Update - GA4 limitations

- Events can have a maximum of 25 parameters.
- Events can have a maximum of 25 user properties.
- User property names must be 24 characters or fewer.
- User property values must be 36 characters or fewer.
- Parameter names (including item parameters) must be 40 characters or fewer, may only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores, and must start with an alphabetic character.
- Parameter values (including item parameter values) must be 100 characters or fewer.
- The post body must be smaller than 130kB.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#required_parameters